# how to read and display multiple image in axes gui matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, display

currently i'm working on a project where i need to read 9 images at once and display them in 9 axes with matlab gui.
I've tried some code but it doesn't work.

```
[file,folder,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.*','MultiSelect','on');

handles.img=cell(1,length(file));

for ifile = 1:length(file)
    filename=fullfile(folder,file(ifile).name);
    image=imread(filename);
    axes(handles.axes{ifile});
    imshow(image);
    handles.img{ifile}=image

end
```

this is the error messages:

```
??? Improper index matrix reference.

Error in ==> guikedelaizulfa>open_Callback at 1098
    filename=fullfile(folder,file(ifile).name);

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> guikedelaizulfa at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)guikedelaizulfa('open_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: see `help uigetfile` and you will see that file is not a structure as in your code

Comment: also: don't use `image` as the name of a variable since its a builtin function

Comment: I've tried to rewrite the uigetfile command and change image to img but i still get same error message. what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the output of [`uigetfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) as if it were the same as the output of [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html). The output of `uigetfile` is simply

```
[files, folder, filterIndex] = uigetfile('*.*','MultiSelect','on');
```

If you look at the values of files, you will see that it is a cell array of filenames and **not** a struct like you are treating it.

```
disp(files)
```

If we work that into your current code:

```
[files, folder, filterIndex] = uigetfile('*.*','MultiSelect','on');

handles.img = cell(1, numel(files));

for ifile = 1:numel(files)
    filename = fullfile(folder, files{ifile});
    img = imread(filename);
    imshow(img, 'Parent', handles.axes{ifile});
    handles.img{ifile} = img;
end
```

In your case where you don't have axes handles, but only axes tags, you could do the following inside the loop

```
ax = findall(gcf, 'type', 'axes', 'tag', sprintf('axes%d', ifile));
imshow(img, 'Parent', ax);
```

Comment: Thank you!! 

I tried your suggestion, but i still get error messages

Comment: ??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array
object.

Error in ==> guikedelaizulfa>open_Callback at 1098
    filename=fullfile(folder,files{ifile});

Comment: Oops, Sorry I had the wrong ordering of the outputs. Updated answer now @ZulfaLuthfi

Comment: I tried it, but i think there's something wrong while i try to display my images in axes. my axes's tag were axes1 - axes9. which command that I should change?

Comment: ?? Reference to non-existent field 'axes'.

Error in ==> guikedelaizulfa>open_Callback at 1100
    imshow(img,'Parent',handles.axes{ifile})

Comment: you have to define handles.axes cell array first. If they have tags you can do something like `handles.axes{1} = findall(gcf, 'type', 'axes', 'tag', 'axes1')`